# Can somebody please tell what is the difference between these two date comparisons?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, date, date-format

So I have 2 queries as follows:

```
f.DATE >= (GETDATE() - 3)

f.DATE >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() - 3,101) AS DATETIME)
```

I think they are the same but the second one gives me more rows than the first one does.
The data type of f.DATE is date though.

Can you please tell me where I get it wrong? Thank you much!!

Comment: Just look at the result of each: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5f859232de7b5d9967d4df347b50a48 Is `f.date` maybe a `datetime` rather than a `date`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the data type of f.date is "date". it confused me though.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server [GETDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function returns the exact date and time as it at the time of execution including the seconds/milisecond i.e. 2020-07-24 14:08:40.670. When the query executes, the

> GETDATE()-3

evaluates the date/time as it at at the time of execution minus 3 days i.e.  2020-07-21 14:08:40.670 and thus only items with an f.Date greater then/equal to  2020-07-21 14:08:40.670 will be returned.

Using [CONVERT with a Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of 101 on GETDATE() returns a date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy. In your example above of

> CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() - 3,101) AS DATETIME)

the

> CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() - 3,101)

evaluates the date/time as it at at the time of execution minus 3 days without any time portion i.e.  2020-07-21. When this is then CAST to a datetime the time portion is defaulted to 00:00:00 i.e. 2020-07-21 00:00:00.000.

As the derived expression in your second statement is earlier than that in the first you may have additional rows returned.

Comment: just run this to see the difference: select GETDATE() - 3,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE() - 3,101) AS DATETIME)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use either of these forms. This  `- 3` shorthand is a timebomb waiting to happen (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) and [this video](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9321/sql-server-date-time-shorthand-and-other-tricks/)), and converting to a string and back is one of the least efficient ways to strip the time from a `datetime` type (see [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)).

If the column is date, you should *explicitly* subtract 3 days from today at midnight, which can be obtained by simply converting "now" to a `date` type:

```
WHERE f.DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -3, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()));
```

As an aside, you also should avoid using reserved words (like `DATE`) as column names.